# Accessing item of QAbstractItemModel via Pointer gets NULL after several reads

Tags: qt, qml, qabstractitemmodel

I need to access items directly of an QAbstractListModel from QML.
I realized it by returning the address from a function from the model:
Function is
**Q_INVOKABLE DataSourceObject *dataPointer(const QModelIndex &index);**

```
#ifndef DATASOURCEMODEL_H
#define DATASOURCEMODEL_H

#include "datasourceobject.h"
#include <QAbstractListModel>

class DataSourceModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    enum datasourceRoles {
        idRole = Qt::UserRole ,
        nameRole,
        unitRole,
        valueRole
    };

    explicit DataSourceModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void addDataSourceObject(DataSourceObject *dataSourceObject);
    Q_INVOKABLE QVariantMap get(int row) const;

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    Q_INVOKABLE QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value,
                 int role = Qt::EditRole) override;
    Q_INVOKABLE DataSourceObject *dataPointer(const QModelIndex &index);
    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex& index) const override;
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override;
    //bool checkIndex(const QModelIndex &index) const;

private:
    QList<DataSourceObject*> m_DataSourceObjects;
};

#endif // DATASOURCEMODEL_H
```

```
#include "datasourcemodel.h"
#include <qdebug.h>

DataSourceModel::DataSourceModel(QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractListModel(parent)
{
}

QVariantMap DataSourceModel::get(int row) const
{
    return m_DataSourceObjects[row]->toMap();
}

void DataSourceModel::addDataSourceObject(DataSourceObject *dataSourceObject)
{
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
    m_DataSourceObjects << dataSourceObject;
    endInsertRows();
}
int DataSourceModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (parent.isValid())
        return 0;
    return m_DataSourceObjects.count();
}

QVariant DataSourceModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if(index.row() < 0 || index.row() >= m_DataSourceObjects.count() || !index.isValid())
        return  QVariant();

    DataSourceObject *dataSourceObject = m_DataSourceObjects[index.row()];
    if (role == idRole)
        return dataSourceObject->id();
    else if (role == nameRole) {
        return dataSourceObject->name();
    }
    else if (role == unitRole) {
        return dataSourceObject->unit();
    }
    else if (role == valueRole)
        return dataSourceObject->value();
    return QVariant();
}

bool DataSourceModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    DataSourceObject *dataSourceObject = m_DataSourceObjects[index.row()];
    if (data(index, role) != value) {
        if(role == idRole)
            dataSourceObject->setId(value.toInt());
        else if(role == nameRole)
            dataSourceObject->setName(value.toString());
        else if(role == unitRole)
            dataSourceObject->setUnit(value.toString());
        else if(role == valueRole)
            dataSourceObject->setValue(value.toDouble());
        emit dataChanged(index, index, QVector<int>() << role);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

DataSourceObject *DataSourceModel::dataPointer(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    qDebug() << m_DataSourceObjects[index.row()];
    return m_DataSourceObjects[index.row()];
}

Qt::ItemFlags DataSourceModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return Qt::NoItemFlags;

    return Qt::ItemIsEditable; // FIXME: Implement me!
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> DataSourceModel::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[idRole] = "id";
    roles[nameRole] = "name";
    roles[unitRole] = "unit";
    roles[valueRole] = "value";
    return  roles;
}
```

I can access the item and it's propertys from QML and the GUI gets automatically updated with Q_PROPERTY on the gui.

```
text: dataSourceModel.dataPointer(dataSourceModel.index(88,0)).value
```

Object:

```
#ifndef DATASOURCEOBJECT_H
#define DATASOURCEOBJECT_H

#include <QString>
#include <QVariantMap>

class DataSourceObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(double value READ value WRITE setValue NOTIFY valueChanged)

public:

    explicit DataSourceObject(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    DataSourceObject(const QJsonObject &obj);
    int id() const;
    void setId(int id);

    QString name() const;
    void setName(const QString &name);

    QString unit() const;
    void setUnit(const QString &unit);

    Q_INVOKABLE double value() const;
    void setValue(double value);
    QVariantMap toMap() const;

signals:
    void valueChanged();


private:
    int m_id;
    QString m_name;
    QString m_unit;
    double m_value;
};

#endif // DATASOURCEOBJECT_H
```

The property "value" of the items get's changed during runtime in background.
After circa 80 changes of the propertys the pointer that points to the object returns NULL. So I assume the item in the model changed it's address.
How can I prevent the model to change the addresses of it's item.
But also when I call again **Q_INVOKABLE DataSourceObject *dataPointer(const QModelIndex &index);** to get the address again, the "old" address ist returned but a "QObject" instead of "DataSourceObject"

Comment: Your code is not an MCVE since it is not what you describe:  *After circa 80 changes of the propertys ...*

Comment: A MCVE is very hard to realize here, I made a downloadable version. Please copy datasources.json into build folder before running. You will see that the counter stops counting  @ 86 . Download https://www.dropbox.com/s/nbhsx8nkvc73jqz/powertune-2.zip?dl=0